# Why did my graph explode?

Tags: tikz-pgf

All I did was change it from `plot ({\x},{1/(\x)})` to `plot ({\x},{1/(\x+1)})` and it turned from a beautiful hyperbola to this monstrosity.

I am guessing it sampled 'too well' and how Tikz works is that it 'jumps' from one end to another, but that got captured because of the sampling.

Here is the code! Unfortunately I am new and do not know how to make the nice big grey box.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\definecolor{bluegraph}{RGB}{0,102,204}
\draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (-2,0)--(2,0)node[below, xshift=-0.12cm]{$x$};
\draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (0,-2)--(0,2)node[left, yshift=-0.15cm]{$y$};
\draw[xscale=0.25, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=-8:-0.5, smooth,variable=\x, bluegraph ,latex-latex] plot ({\x},{1/(\x+1)});
\draw[xscale=0.25, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=0.5:8, smooth,variable=\x, bluegraph ,latex-latex] plot ({\x},{1/(\x+1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently the graph is split to remove the asymptotes at `x=0`, but you moved the location of this asymptote to `x=-1`, so you would have to adjust this splitting. But we can't guess how it's done and how to fix it without seeing the code that generated the monstrosity. Could you please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Off-topic: excellent title.

Answer (score 10):

Your graph has two plots, not only one, and both stopped 0.5 units distant from the asymptote.

The first one stopped at `-0.5` and the second started back at `0.5`. I subtracted `1` from them, so `-1.5` and `-0.5`.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
  \definecolor{bluegraph}{RGB}{0,102,204}
  \draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (-2,0)--(2,0)node[below, xshift=-0.12cm]{$x$};
  \draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (0,-2)--(0,2)node[left, yshift=-0.15cm]{$y$};
  %                               changed the domain here vvv
  \draw[xscale=0.25, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=-8:-1.5, smooth,variable=\x, bluegraph ,latex-latex] plot ({\x},{1/(\x+1)});
  %                                           and here vvv
  \draw[xscale=0.25, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=-0.5:8, smooth,variable=\x, bluegraph ,latex-latex] plot ({\x},{1/(\x+1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

A version with the same length of the domain to each side and a dotted line to show the asymptote:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
  \definecolor{bluegraph}{RGB}{0,102,204}
  \definecolor{dottedred}{RGB}{182,67,80}
  \draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (-2.25,0)--(1.75,0) node [below, xshift=-0.12cm]{$x$};
  \draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (0,-2)--(0,2) node [right, yshift=-0.15cm]{$y$};
  \draw[line width=0.5pt, densely dotted, dottedred] (-0.25,-2)--(-0.25,2);
  %                               changed the domain here vvv
  \draw[xscale=0.25, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=-9:-1.5, smooth,variable=\x, bluegraph ,latex-latex] plot ({\x},{1/(\x+1)});
  %                                           and here vvv
  \draw[xscale=0.25, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=-0.5:7, smooth,variable=\x, bluegraph ,latex-latex] plot ({\x},{1/(\x+1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

your graph has singularity at -1, so it can not be drawn in one piece. with small  use of the math it is possible to calculate the  `x` value at which is for example `y=4` (it is at -1.25 and - 0.75) and than split them to two graphs, left from example from `x=-4` to `x=-1.25` and right from `x=-0.75` to `x=4`. considering this and with small changes of your diagram code, you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\definecolor{bluegraph}{RGB}{0,102,204}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%baseline=(current bounding box.north), % why you need this?
    scale=0.5,
arr/.style = {line width=1pt, smooth,bluegraph, latex-latex},
                        ]
% axis
\draw[-{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[-{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (0,-4)--(0,4) node[below left] {$y$};
\draw[densely dashed] (-1,-4) -- + (0,8);
% curve
\draw[arr, domain=-4:-1.25] plot (\x,{1/(\x+1)});
\draw[arr, domain=-0.75: 4] plot (\x,{1/(\x+1)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How could one improve the tip position of blue arrows (1) most right one above "x", and, (2) most left one below the x-axis. I registered some overlapping edges?

Comment: indeed. i didn't notice befor. this discrepancy will disappear if you remove line with `sample=100`. see edited answer.